# Print 1st word of 1st column and 2nd word of 2nd column in a single line

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I would like to print first word of first column and second word of second column in to a single column 
Example:

```
ABC 123
BCD 987
```

output:

```
ABC 987
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please use backticks(`) to put code tags, as your Input is not clear, please do let me know if any queries on same.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet and simple awk may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{val=$1;next} FNR==2{print val,$2}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk 'FNR==1{printf $1 OFS;next}FNR==2{print $2;exit}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

this will extract the diagonal for arbitrary size table

```
$ awk '{print $NR}' file | paste -sd' ' -
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `-` to read from stdin `awk '{print $NR}' file | paste -sd' ' -`

Comment: If I don't put the `-` at the end I get: `usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...
` probably this only happens in macOS/FreeBSD

Comment: Yes, I think the default without filename is std input.  Your version might be explicitly needing the filename or `-` for stdin.

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed 'N;s/\([^ ]*\)\(.*\n[^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3/' infile
```

Or

```
sed -E 'N;s/([^ ]+)(.*\n[^ ]+)(.*)/\1\3/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

using **awk**

```
$ awk '{printf $NR (NR==2?ORS:" ") }' file
ABC 987
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/ .* / /' file
```

Append the second line to the first and replace everything between the first two spaces with another space.